# argparse with user input for files to produce a graph

Tags: python-2.7

I have a long code to extract data from fasta files, and draw a graph with them. I want to use argparse to call the programme and do what it suppose to do. But I am having a few problems, and this is what I have done so far:
 import argparse
1.openfiles to extract data, open them via raw_input
2.def create condition for graph
3.def another condition for grap
4.def makeamatrix
5.def plotmatrix
6.def mygraph
  #mygraph(objectA, objectB, A, J)

> 7.def main():
>
> parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="create my dot plot")
>
> > ```
> > parser.add_argument('--fileA',help="First file")
> > parser.add_argument('--fileB', help='Second file')
> > parser.add_argument('--objectA',help='my first ')
> > parser.add_argument('--objectB',help='my second ')t
> > parser.add_argument('--A',type=int)
> > parser.add_argument('--J',type=float)
> > args=parser.parse_args()
> > mygraph(args.objectA,args.objectB,args.A,args.J)
> >  if __name__ == '__main__':
> > main(
> > ```
> >
> > I am calling the function as:
> >      myfunction.py --fileA   --fileB, --A 1 --J 2
> >     Obviously it is not working. What I want it to do it to extract the data from the files to produce the graph. Otherwise there is a method I can called my function as:
> >     myfuchtion.py -fileA -fileB -A 1 -J 2, and produce the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of calling the function as `myfunction.py --fileA --fileB, --A 1 --J 2`, you will need to pass values for the `--fileA` and `--fileB` options:

```
 myfunction.py --fileA /some/file --fileB /some/other/file --A 1 --J 2
```

Then you haven't passed either of the `--object` options.

The code shown here doesn't use the `--file` options, but if they hold the data then you will need to open them and read them. For instance:

```
with open(args.fileA) as f:
    dataA = f.read()
```

You can get `argparse` to open them for you by using `type=argparse.FileType('r')`, then:

```
dataA = args.fileA.read()
args.fileA.close()
```

but you have to close it yourself.

See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html for details.

In your comment you ask about calling the script as

```
myfunction myfile myfile2 -A 1(or any other choice of number) -J 2 (or any number of my choice)
```

Here's how you do that with `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument('fileA',help="First file")
parser.add_argument('fileB', help='Second file')
parser.add_argument('-A',type=int)
parser.add_argument('-J',type=float)
args=parser.parse_args()
```

If you call the script as above, then

`args.fileA` is `"myfile"`

`args.fileB` is `"myfile2"`

`args.A` is `1`

`args.J` is `2`

So if the mygraph function takes filenames, call it like this:

```
mygraph(args.fileA, args.fileB, args.A, args.J)
```

Otherwise read the data from the files and pass that instead, e.g.

```
with open(args.fileA) as f1:
    data1 = f1.read()
with open(args.fileB) as f2:
    data2 = f2.read()
mygraph(data1, data2, args.A, args.J)
```

That works if the `mygraph` function takes a string. If not, you will have to parse the contents into whatever form your function wants.

Comment: I have been reading all that documentation but for a beginner is overwhelming. And to be honest I don't know how to manage that one. Is there any one using sys.arg, that I can manage better to be able to called the function specifically as : myfunction myfile myfile2 -A 1(or anyother choice of number) -J 2 ( of any number of my choice?.

Comment: What my code does it to open two files, extract data from it, and produce a graph with the extracted data.

Comment: The first way of calling it should work, in that case.